# Problema bcrypt laravel 5.5 no funciona

Tags: laravel-5

Alguien sabe como poner un bcrypt en el campo password de este metodo?

```html
   /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id) 
    {

        $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin']);
        $this->validate($request,['name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password'=>'required|string|min:6|confirmed', 'password_confirmation'=>'required|min:6|same:password', 'tipos_usuarios_id']); 
 
        user::find($id)->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('ecuentas.index')->with('success','Registro actualizado satisfactoriamente');
    }
```

Bueno en mi modelo solo tengo esto,

```html
  protected $fillable = [
        'tipos_usuarios_id', 'name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
```

Como podria validar desde un modelo, hasta ahora solo lo estaba haciendo en el controlador

Answer (score 0):

la validación te recomiendo que la hagas en el modelo, no en el controlador.

Intentaste colocarlo así:  $this->validate($request,['name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password' => Bcrypt('123456')

Esta validación hazla en el modelo... 'required|string|min:6|confirmed'

Comment: solucion    user::find($id)->update(['name'=>$request['name'], 'last_name'=>$request['last_name'], 'username'=>$request['username'], 'mail'=>$request['mail'], 'password'=>bcrypt($request['password'])]);

Comment: por que en el modelo?

Comment: Me parece mejor, queda más limpio el código del controlador

Comment: Disculpa, crea un Request, no en el modelo... Hoy estoy un poco descuidado